# Getting Logging Working in a Python Click Application

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is the current tree of my code:

```
Click_test/
├── cli.py
├── cool_stuff
│   ├── commands.py
│   ├── __init__.py
|
├── __init__.py
```

Parent CLI File looks like this:

```
import click
import cool_stuff.commands as cool_stuff

@click.group()
@click.argument("secret", case_sensitive=False)
@click.pass_context
def cli(ctx, secret):
    ctx.obj['secret'] = secret

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cli.add_command(cool_stuff.do_something)
    cli(obj={})
```

Commands.py file looks like this:

```
import click
from tqdm import tqdm
import logging

FORMAT = "%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s"
logging.basicConfig(format=FORMAT, filename="a_log.log", filemode="w", level=logging.DEBUG)

@click.command("do_something")
@click.pass_context
def do_something(ctx):
    click.echo(f'Doing some cool stuff...')
    for number in tqdm(range(100), description="Do some cool things"):
        logging.debug(f"Secret is {ctx.obj['secret']} {number}")
```

For some reason, when I run it in this format, the logger doesn't work properly. There is no "a_log.log" file while this runs or after. I even removed the filename to have it print to stdout and it still wouldn't.

When I don't use the .group() construct and just have it under a single command, no problem. Has anyone ever experienced this before? The intention of putting it in this format is I don't have one giant file full of commands. Another option is to eliminate the group portion of it if possible and still be able to break out the commands into separate files based on certain categories.